# HttpPost with AJAX call help needed

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

what else do i need in my code please, I have this so far:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function PostNewsComment(newsId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "<%= Url.Action("AddCommentOnNews", "Home", new { area = "News" }) %>?newsId=" + newsId + "&newsComment=" + $("#textareaforreply").val(), success: function (data) {
      $("#news-comment-content").html(data + $("#news-comment-content").html());
      type: 'POST'
    }
  });
}
$("#textareaforreply").val("");
</script>
```

and

```
    [HttpPost]
[NoCache]
public ActionResult AddCommentOnNews(int newsId, string newsComment)
{
  if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newsComment))
  {
    var currentUser = ZincService.GetUserForId(CurrentUser.UserId);
    ZincService.NewsService.AddCommentOnNews(newsId, newsComment, currentUser.UserId);

    Zinc.DataModels.News.NewsCommentsDataModel model = new DataModels.News.NewsCommentsDataModel();
    var today = DateTime.UtcNow;
    model.CommentDateAndTime = today;
    model.NewsComment = newsComment;
    model.Firstname = currentUser.Firstname;
    model.Surname = currentUser.Surname;
    model.UserId = CurrentUser.UserId;
    return View("NewsComment", model);
  }

  return null;
}


<div class="actions-right">    
  <a href="javascript:PostNewsComment(<%: Model.News.NewsId %>);" class="button" id="post_button"><%: Html.Resource(Resources.Global.Button.Reply) %></a>                
</div>
```

i have no idea how this works, because it is not working in FF???
and the other thing is i must not pass return null i must pass JSON false ???

any help please?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode your request parameters. Right now you have concatenated them to the request with a strong concatenation which is a wrong approach. There's a property called `data` that allows you to pass parameters to an AJAX request and leave the proper url encoding to the framework:

```
function PostNewsComment(newsId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= Url.Action("AddCommentOnNews", "Home", new { area = "News" }) %>', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
            newsId: newsId, 
            newsComment: $('#textareaforreply').val() 
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#news-comment-content').html(data + $('#news-comment-content').html());
        }
    });
}
```

Also you haven't shown where and how you are calling this `PostNewsComment` function but if this happens on the click of a link or submit button make sure that you have canceled the default action by returning false, just like that:

```
$('#someLink').click(function() {
    PostNewsComment('123');
    return false;
});
```

> and the other thing is i must not pass return null i must pass JSON false ???

You could have your controller action return a `JsonResult` in this case:

```
return Json(new { success = false });
```

and then inside your success callback you could test for this condition:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (!data.success) {
        // the server returned a Json result indicating a failure
        alert('Oops something bad happened on the server');
    } else {
        // the server returned the view => we can go ahead and update our DOM
        $('#news-comment-content').html(data + $('#news-comment-content').html());
    }
}
```

Another thing you should probably be aware of is the presence of dangerous characters such as `<` or `>` in the comment text. To allow those characters I would recommend you build a view model and decorate the corresponding property with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute:

```
public class NewsViewModel
{
    public int NewsId { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Required]
    public string NewsComment { get; set; }
}
```

Now your controller action will obviously take the view model as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
[NoCache]
public ActionResult AddCommentOnNews(NewsViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var currentUser = ZincService.GetUserForId(CurrentUser.UserId);
        ZincService.NewsService.AddCommentOnNews(viewModel.NewsId, viewModel.NewsComment, currentUser.UserId);

        var model = new DataModels.News.NewsCommentsDataModel();
        var today = DateTime.UtcNow;
        model.CommentDateAndTime = today;
        model.NewsComment = newsComment;
        model.Firstname = currentUser.Firstname;
        model.Surname = currentUser.Surname;
        model.UserId = CurrentUser.UserId;
        return View("NewsComment", model);
    }

    return Json(new { success = false });
}
```

Comment: thanks very much but i think there is something missing still cos I get the alert('Oops something bad happened on the server') ?? the return in my controller  calls a partial called NewsComment, do I need something else please? thanks

Comment: What happened when you debugged your server side controller action? Are the action parameters passed correctly?

Comment: In fire bug:

newsComment aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
newsId 120
Source
newsId=120&newsComment=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
action parameters contain correct values

Comment: Great so your controller action is successfully invoked with correct parameters.

Comment: That's because your controller action doesn't return a View but Json. Have you verified why your `if` statement is not satisfied and you didn't reach the `return View` statement?

Comment: it does go into the if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newsComment)) but when it gets to return View(...) it jumps to the last } just after the return Json?? and model does contain all the values it should

Comment: Alright so you are not returning a json but a view. Then the `if (!data.success)` statement on the client should not be satisfied and you should enter the `else` part.

Comment: but i dont? i enter the (!data.success) I dont understand? what am i missing? i am testing in FF

Comment: Could you put a `console.log(data);` inside your `success` callback and paste what you are seeing as output in your console here?